# Real time element width using range output value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, width, element

As the title says I want to get output value from range input - (`#inputValue`)  and immediately when the value of range is changed, it will change element width (`#box`) as well.

I've created "button" (`#buttonToApply`) onclick function, which is working properly, but is needed to click button after the value is changed to apply new width.

```js
/* This one work, after clicking button */
$("#buttonToApply").click(function(){
$("#box").width($("#inputValue").val() + "px");  
});
/* This one doesn't, real time */
$("#box").width($("#inputValue").val() + "px");
```

```css
#box {
  background: orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <input id="inputValue" type="range" min="100" max="300" step="50">
<br/><br/>
  <button id="buttonToApply">change width</button>
<br/><br/>
  <div id="box"></div>
  
</center>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to run the code that sets the width of the `div` under the `change` event of the range slider, like this:

```js
$("#buttonToApply").click(function() {
  $("#box").width($("#inputValue").val() + "px");
});

$('#inputValue').change(function() {
  $("#box").width($(this).val() + "px");
});
```

```css
#box {
  background: orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <input id="inputValue" type="range" min="100" max="300" step="50"><br/><br/>
  <button id="buttonToApply">change width</button><br/><br/>
  <div id="box"></div>
</center>
```

Also, just FYI, the `<center>` tag has been deprecated. You should now set `text-align` in your CSS rules instead.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. I've used <center> just now to quickly align everything to center.